# Angular Material not Working in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material in Angular 9, and it is not working for me. It is compiling and running, but every time I use Angular Material in my HTML, such as mat-checkbox or mat-form-field, it isn't working properly. I even tried straight up copying the code from material.angular.io, and it is still not working.

[image]

I circled the one I am trying to do. Mine turned out like this:

[image]

The code is the same, except I used a different placeholder and label, and I did not use the mat-hint feature. I have imported the module in my app.module.ts properly, so I don't know what is wrong. Here is my code I used.

```
<div class="false" *ngIf="!authorized">
      <h4>In order to complete the sign up process, we need the authorized person from your organization <br>to review our terms and conditions. You can send them an email below.</h4>
      <br>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Authorized Person's Name</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Authorized Person's Name">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <button mat-button class="email">Send Email</button>
</div>
```

Is there something I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

Update: Here is my app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import  { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { PortalComponent } from './portal/portal.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PortalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Are you importing required modules?

Comment: Can you paste your app.module code here to check what's going wrong?

Comment: Yes I believe I am importing the correct modules. I pasted the code just now.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the chrome dev tools console?

Comment: No, just warnings

Comment: So I tried uninstalling angular/material and reinstalling it, and I am getting an error now. First of all, I have 294 low severity vulnerabilities, all to do with prototype pollution on lodash, and when I run the project on ng serve, I get core.js:183 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor MatCommonModule cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score -3, accepted):

it turns out the answer was really simple. I just had to update a couple of my dependencies. Hope this answer helps for anyone who forgets to do the same in the future.

Comment: What were they and how did u find them

Comment: I used ng update in the command prompt and it gave me a list. I don't recall which ones they were sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.module.ts`

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Then in your `component.ts`

```
<div class="false" *ngIf="!authorized">
  <h4>In order to complete the sign up process, we need the authorized person from your organization <br>to review our terms and conditions. You can send them an email below.</h4>
  <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Authorized Person's Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Authorized Person's Name">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>
  <button mat-button class="email">Send Email</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out based on how @angular/material was installed, the result is not going to be the same. If it was installed using npm, I suggest you run `npm uninstall @angular/material` and reinstall it with the angular cli using `ng add @angular/material`.